# How to store and retrieve data in userdefault? (Ex:Array of Struct )

Tags: swift, userdefaults

```
struct ExpandableNames:Codable {
    var isExpanded: Bool
    var names: [String]
    var icons: [String]
} 

var names = ["Food/Drink", "Tours", "Transport", "Gifts","Flights", "Shopping", "Activities","Entertainment","Accomodation","Other"]
var icons = ["Food_Category", "Tours", "Transport_Category", "Gifts_Category","Flights_Category","Shopping_Category","Activities_category","Entertainment_category", "Accomodation_Category","Other_Category"]

var categoryWholeArray = [Int:ExpandableNames]()
```

How to store `categoryWholeArray` to user default?

I tried

Store userDefault:

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(categoryWholeArray), forKey:"categoryWholeArray")
```

Retrieve data problem is here

```
   if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"categoryWholeArray") as? Data {
                      let songs2 = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<categoryWholeArray.values>.self, from: data)
}
```

Anyone tried?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

All correct except

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"categoryWholeArray") as? Data {
    let songs2 = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode([Int:ExpandableNames].self, from: data)
    print(songs2)
}
```

Comment: `songs2` was declared, `song2` was used. Typo?

Comment: Not my downvote but UserDefaults it is not meant for storing data. It should only be used for storing the preferences

Comment: Btw you shouldn't use `value(forKey:)` it is meant for KVO. UserDefaults has a specific method to retrieve data called `data(forKey:)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `encode` data while storing in `UserDefaults` and when you try to get those data you must need to `decode` it.

Here is `extension` i have that might help you.

```
extension UserDefaults {

    func setCustomObjToUserDefaults(CustomeObj: AnyObject, forKey:String) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: CustomeObj)
        defaults.set(encodedData, forKey: forKey)
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

    func getCustomObjFromUserDefaults(forKey:String) -> AnyObject? {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if defaults.object(forKey: forKey) != nil {
            if let decoded  = defaults.object(forKey: forKey) as? Data {
                let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with:decoded) as AnyObject
                return decodedTeams
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func setJsonObject<T: Encodable>(encodable: T, forKey key: String) {
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(encodable) {
            set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }

    func getJsonObject<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: String) -> T? {
        if let data = object(forKey: key) as? Data,
            let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data) {
            return value
        }
        return nil
    }

    func removeCustomObject(forKey:String)
    {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: forKey)
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

}
```

Comment: Let me know if you still need help @ManikandanS